# __respond_to_eh__ in Rubinius, eh?

Tags: ruby, rubinius

In Rubinius, if you do

```
rbx-head > Object.instance_methods.grep(/^_.*/)
 => ["__extend__", "__show__", "__marshal__", "__instance_of__", "__instance_variable_get__", "__send__", "__id__", "__instance_variable_set__", "__respond_to_eh__", "__instance_variables__", "__class__", "__kind_of__", "__instance_variable_defined_eh__", "__nil__", "__metaclass__", "__fixnum__", "__method__"]
```

which includes `"__respond_to_eh__"` and `"__instance_variable_defined_eh__"`.

So this is because the Rubinius folk want to wrap method names that shouldn't be messed with with `__`, and you aren't allowed to use `?` before the end of a method name, [eh?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eh)

Comment: This should probably be asked directly to the Rubinius folk.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Why? Because it's too specialized for SO?

Comment: very likely too specialized. Nobody has even ventured a response or comment so I suspect it's whizzing by everyone's heads. There are some questions I have periodically I'll take directly to developers on a gem or app. SO is a great resource, but it's kind of a general questions kinda place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've now [changed](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/issues/closed#issue/658) to using `__instance_variable_defined_p__` and `__respond_to_p__` in predicates like everywhere else, according to their comments.

Meh.